# The spacing of the stripes on the screen

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection

A point light source is placed at the focal point of the thin lens, and a double prism is placed behind the thin lens, as shown in the figure below. The apex angle of the double prism is $\alpha$(a small amount), the refractive index is $n$, and the wavelength of light is $λ$. Then, what is the spacing of the stripes on the screen?

[image]

I don't have any ideas about the problem, can anyone help?

Comment: Hello. Please annotate you drawing, including Lens, Prism, Screen, and any angles, distances that are relevant. From the drawing it looks like the top and bottom halves of the prism are different. Please confirm and annotate. Finally, which stripes are you talking about?

Comment: I just annotated my drawing, the prism is symmetric. And I am talking about the stripes formed by the light.

Comment: Certainly does not look symmetric - this is confusing. Where is the light coming from? At what angle? Uniform illumination? Collimated or focused? What is the lens-to-prism distance, what is the prism to screen distance? What is the angle on the prism (don't just write in the text - annotate on the picture). In principle this is easily done with matrix optics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Light from point source at the focal point of the lens will come out parallel to axis.
- Deflection due to the prism can be calculated using Snell's law (check   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism#Deviation_angle_and_dispersion  which shows solution approach in detail)